# Filter that has worked for a year just stopped working and now takes me to an error page

Tags: bug

I have a filter that just stopped working yesterday and I can't figure out how to make it work, how to edit it or how to remove it because trying to select the filter just takes me to an error screen.

This is the URL for the filter:

```
http://stackexchange.com/filters/150086/socket-io
```

When I try to go to that filter, it takes me to this error page:

```
http://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/filters/150086/socket-io
```

All my other filters are still working fine.  I have remade the filter under a slightly different name so, at this point I just want to remove the old filter, but because I cannot select it to edit it, I can't get to the place where you would delete it.

Also, this is a note to the site admins that something broke here recently.  I don't know if something got corrupted in a database or a code rev somehow broke this particular filter or something else went wrong.  So, beyond just getting my filter fixed or deleted, if this happened to me, it may have happened to some other users too.

Here's the error page it takes me to:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the details of how the filter is setup? Is it all sites for a given list of tags? Which tags?

Comment: @AnnaLear - sorry, but I can't get to it to see it to see exactly what it's set for.  It's probably all sites for one tag.

Comment: Added screenshot of error page that comes up when I just try to see the results of a filter.

Comment: No repro for me. Is it fixed for you too now?

Comment: @Anna in case it's still relevant, details are: All Sites, tags: `socket.io`,  `websocket`, `socket.io-1.0`, `engine.io`

Comment: @ShadowWizard - After being broken for a little more than 24hrs that filter is working now.  FYI, I started having the same trouble with other filters late last night too.  All are working now.